Azure Logic Apps - Condition Notify issue
I actually wish to get notified on my VM Stop logic app but I am stuck with getting a status when a VM is successfully stopped or failed. I always get only Failed message so I guess I put wrong condition in the flow.
Setup:
Condition

parameter

I tried various setups none working.

Can you provide full design, from where are you getting the status code?

I was getting it  @RithwikBojja from the Deallocate Output in the run history "statusCode": 200,
But maybe thats not the correct approach to get a notification if the VM was successfully stopped or not. I am open to any solution :)

So, if it is stopped and get if you get 200 , you want an email right?

I wish to get a confirmation email if its stopped yes, besides that I wish to get an email also if its failed to stop.

@RithwikBojja I was only able to make something like this:
https://imgur.com/a/tGPtglC

Below design worked for me:
Firstly, just add outlook action and then a parallel path after Deallocating action :

Then again add send an email option:

In code view in second email action change the run after to failed:

Now the design changes to dotted line:

Leave the first one as Succeeded only.
Output:



Thank you! Working like a charm. @rithwikbojja

Glad to know that.
